# How to stop glitching audio in Windows 11?

Tags: audio, windows-11

I have an XPS 8950 with a 12th gen i9 CPU, RTX3080, 32GB RAM, NVME SSD, Widows 11 Home.

About 1 week ago something started happening with the audio.

Every 5-10 seconds there is a slight glitch, like the audio is catching up. It happens with video audio and audio only playback and with gaming.

The video does not glitch, but the game (MW2) glitches at the same time as the audio. So the screen freezes at the same time as the audio glitch.

I have tried:

Updating Realtek audioo drivers
Rolling back audio drivers
uninstalling audio drivers altogether (Windows reinstalls them automatically)
Updating the Graphics drivers
Uninstalling the graphics drivers
reinstalling the graphics drivers
disabeling effects
enabling effects
disabeling audio enhancements
enabling audio enhancements
disabeling spatial audio
enabling spatial audio
Uninstalled Max Audio
Reinstalling Max Audio
disabeling Max Audio enhancements
enabling Max Audio enhancements
Changing the format
Using the front IO wired headphones
Using the back IO wired headphones
Tried alll the Windows troubleshooters

Some of these (updating graphics card, uninstalling and reinstalling the Realtek Audio driver) fixed the problem for a short while after restarting the computer, but its back to glitching within an hour.

The Task Manager is not showing anything abnormal either.

I have no idea what else to do!

Is there anything else I can do, short of reinstalling windows?

Comment: You could try disabling everything running at startup and make sure everything else that isn't your game is closed too.  The sysinternals [autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) utility is a good way to get to the whole list.  Does it still happen?

Comment: I had placed an answer, but it only worked for so long, adding here for completion. I uninstalled Geforce HD Audio and that has fixed the problem - for about a week and then it was back to glitching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given all you have done, there is not a lot of choice left.

**(1)** Try a Windows 11 Repair Install and Keep Everything.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.

Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.

Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.

Proceed normally answering the prompts.

The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(2)** If the Repair works, great. If not, then back up all of your information and reinstall Windows.

You can normally do this from the Update, Recovery section. Use Reset and Keep Nothing.

If you are unsure about doing Repairs, just back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: I did a fresh install.